# Use standard scaler in combination with min max?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-scaling

I asked a colleague if it would be wrong to use feature scaling in decision trees since it is not required by the algorithm. He said that not only I could, but also it is a good practice. However, he implied that I should use standard scaler to bring the data to mean 0 and have the same variance, and afterwards, apply min max to transform in a range from 0 to 1. I have never heard this concept before. Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: This is mathematically redundant, because you would get exactly the same result by just scaling to the unit interval at the outset.  Perhaps you and your colleague have miscommunicated: consider asking him/her for clarification.